# DynamoDB NoSQL and Failed to instantiate new instance of class

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, nosql, mapper

Need some help with  AmazonDynamoDB (NoSQL) but I believe its a general error AmazonDynamoDB not related.

Here is a class below to work with DB, talbe name=table and has 2 columns PhraseID(integer, key column) and phrase (string).

```
 @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table")
   public class Phrase {
    private Integer PhraseID;
    private String phrase;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "phraseID")
    public Integer getID()
    { return PhraseID;  }

    public void setID(Integer PhraseID) {
        this.PhraseID = PhraseID;}

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "phrase")
    public String getPhrase()
    { return phrase;     }

    public void setPhrase(String phrase)
    {  this.phrase = phrase;     }

}
```

I have no problems writing/updating this table with mapper.save (phrase) via phrase.setID and etc  but not with reading/loading. I call this readDB by: new  readDB().execute("");

```
private class readDB extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new          AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider); //sdk-ddb
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
        int a=1;
        mapper.load(Phrase.class, a);  //want to load a phrase from db with phraseID=1
        return "Executed";
    }
}
```

So Im getting the error: "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: **Failed to instantiate new instance of class**" and one more below **"Main activity Phrase has no zero argument constructor"**

Googling this error gives me an answer  that I "need to create a default constructor to solve this exception" but I dont really understand what exactly I need to do / change in my code.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this exception comes from here :
https://github.com/Widen/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java (line 291)

It means there is no default constructor to the class, is it possible that you defined non default constructor to phrase ? try to add

```
public Phrase(){}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Im really sorry, But I didnt get it. Where should I add this line?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.
DynamoDBMapper creates a new instance of the class when try to access the table for the sake of marshalling.
try writing a constructor for your class.
worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Each table class must be subclass in the parent class that manipulate each table class.

Comment: I'm sorry the above way is not technically the solution.
I could solve the issue when each table class is the static class.